# How could a question on Source Control hosting be migrated to Super User?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I asked [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247250/assembla-vs-unfuddle-for-subversion-hosting) on SO related to source control hosting, which was, by the way, very similar to the following 2 questions:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384/opinion-of-hosted-svn-providers
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297153/can-you-recommend-a-svn-closed-source-project-hosting-site

Strangely, it was closed and migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/107701/assembla-vs-unfuddle-for-subversion-hosting) for the following reason: "This question is related to computer hardware or computer software in general, and is a better fit for Super User."

Predictably, the guys on SU closed it, deeming it "not computer related".

My question is - how does a question on Subversion Source Control get closed on SO - and worse, migrated to SU? Obviously I believe that this question has a lot of relevance to programmers, as it is merely a refinement or call for further clarity if you will, of two other highly-upvoted questions on SO (29 upvotes between them).

Comment: Because it wasn't C# or Java, so they moved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question had other problems -- it's subjective, it's kind of a duplicate, and also a poll, which is strongly discouraged.

Comment: I will readily admit that it was subjective, and that it was a poll. However, it really isn't a duplicate. There were two very similar questions which produced contradictory answers and I wished to have the community decide between the two in a very direct way.

Comment: @Ryan: That's the equivalent of giving out weapons to two opposing parties and watch the fight from a safe distance.

Comment: That's still no reason to migrate it to SU though.